# WCF Message Contract and Streaming

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, stream, messagecontract

I'm going boarder line crazy, I have been working with this for over a day and still have no idea why it doesn't work,

I have a MessageContract that I'm using to send out a stream, but I get the following error,

> Type 'System.IO.FileStream' with data
>   contract name
>   'FileStream:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO'
>   is not expected. Add any types not
>   known statically to the list of known
>   types - for example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
>   adding them to the list of known types
>   passed to DataContractSerializer.

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IContentService
{
    [OperationContract(), FaultContract(typeof(ContentFault))]
    PublishItemResponse PublishFile(PublishFileRequest request);
}


[MessageContract()]
public class PublishFileRequest
{ 
 [MessageHeader()]
 public FileInventoryItem Item {get;set;}

 [MessageHeader()]
 public Request Request  {get;set;}

 [MessageBodyMember()]
 public Stream FileContent {get;set;}
}



 [MessageContract()]
 public class Request
 {
  [MessageHeader()]
  public Guid AuthorizationToken { get; set; }

  [MessageHeader()]
  public string CoreVersion  { get; set; }

  [MessageHeader()]
  public string Password { get; set; }

  [MessageHeader()]
  public DateTime RequestTime { get; set; }

  [MessageHeader()]
  public string ComponentVersion { get; set; }

  [MessageHeader()]
  public string UserName  { get; set; }
 }



[MessageContract()]
[Serializable()]
public class FileInventoryItem : InventoryItemBase
{
 public Stream FileContent { get; set;}
}



[MessageContract()]
[KnownType(typeof(FileInventoryItem))]
[KnownType(typeof(FolderInventoryItem))]
[Serializable()]
public abstract class InventoryItemBase
{
 public List<string> Errors {get;set;}

 public List<string> Warnings  {get;set;}

 [MessageHeader()]
 public StagingAction Action {get;set;}

 [MessageHeader()]
 public string ContentXml  {get;set;}

 [MessageHeader()]
 public int ItemId {get;set;}

 [MessageHeader()]
 public ItemType ItemType { {get;set;}

 [MessageHeader()]
 public string Name  {get;set;}

 [MessageHeader()]
 public int ParentId {get;set;}

 [MessageHeader()]
 public Guid ParentUniqueId  {get;set;}

 [MessageHeader()]
 public Guid UniqueId  {get;set;}

 [MessageHeader()]
 public Guid Version  {get;set;}
}
```

Any help is greatly appropriated,

Comment: The error mentions `System.IO.FileStream`. There is no FileStream in your ServiceContract. Why?

Comment: [MessageBodyMember()]
public Stream FileContent {get;set;}

what is being passed in is a File-stream which is inherited from Stream.

Comment: *Inherited* from Stream. That's the problem. Have you tried to send just a pure Stream to see if it works?

Comment: Can't really do that since Stream is an abstract type

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: In case you haven't seen this post on SO, it may cast some light on the reason why this isn't working http://stackoverflow.com/a/1322817/132599.

Answer (score 0):

WCF requires the types that are serialized to exactly match the types that are declared in the contract. You can get around that by adding the [KnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute to indicate that you know a particular sub type is going to be used (in this case you would add it to the PublishFileRequest class).

However, while that will eliminate the first error, your code will still not work, since FileStreams are not serializable.

Comment: File streams are not serializable by xml serilizer, they are serilizable using the messagecontract serilizer. I have got a FileStream across application in an isolated environment, it just doesn't seem to work in that particular setup.

Comment: Maybe using DAtacontract and not messagecontract ?

Answer (score 0):

The FileStream object points to the filesystem, which cannot be accessed from another computer.

Use a MemoryStream instead to transfer the data. You can use Stream.CopyTo(memoryStream) to copy the data to the MemoryStream object.