# KnownType for MessageContract in WCF

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, datacontract, messagecontract, known-types

I am using `Stream` object inside my wcf Contracts so forced to use `MessageContract` instead of `DataContract`.

```
 [MessageContract]
    public class Document 
    {
        [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
        public System.IO.Stream FileData;

}

 [MessageContract]
    public class A : Document 
    {
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string input;

}

 [MessageContract]
    public class B : Document 
    {
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string someProp;

}

[ServiceContract]
    public interface ISomeService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        Document SomeMethod(Document file);
}
```

I want the consumer of this service to create object of either A or B and call the service with it. On the service side, I can type cast it to proper object then perform some action.

Problem is I cannot specified `KnownType` with `MessageContract` and inherited contracts cannot be exposed to client until they are used in service or declared with `KnownType`.

I tried google it but couldn't find anything related to `KnownType` with `MessageContract`.

As suggested in comment... i updated my message contract with `KnownType` but they are still not exposed to client through service reference...

```
[MessageContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(FileSystemStoredDocument))]
    [KnownType(typeof(FileBoundStoredDocument))]
    [KnownType(typeof(SharepointStoredDocument))]

    public class Document : DocumentInfo, IDisposable
    {
}
```

Can any one help me what's wrong here?

**Note**: ALL `KnownType` are inherited from `Document`

Comment: What you are saying seems wrong to me. AFAIK you can sure use `KnownType` on `MessageContract`. But i do believe to remember, streams are not Serializable, wich means you will not be able to transfer them. Also have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208866/wcf-message-contract-and-streaming)

Comment: Can you post the exception? Also, did you mark `DocumentInfo` as known-type too?

Comment: There is no exception. I can't simple see derived types in proxy generated code. and Document info is not mentioned as knownType as it is already part of one of the method in service contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Message contracts describe *exactly how the message should look like*. They do support inheritance, but you must specify the exact message contract you're using in a specific operation.

If you check the body parts of the message:

```
ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(ISomeService)).Operations[0].Messages[0].Body.Parts
```

You'll see exactly one part - a `Stream` object. That's in contrast to data contracts, where the body contains a part of the type `Object`. So you see why **`KnownType` wouldn't work here**.

(The `ContractDescription` class is used, among other things, to generate WSDL. See the `WsdlExporter` class.)

What you *can* do is create a hierarchy of data contracts that would be contained in the message contract, e.g.

```
[MessageContract]
public class Document 
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public DocumentProperties Properties;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public System.IO.Stream FileData;
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(A))]
[KnownType(typeof(B))]
public abstract class DocumentProperties { }

[DataContract]
public class A : DocumentProperties 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string input;
}

[DataContract]
public class B : DocumentProperties 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string someProp;
}
```

Note that you you cannot have more than one body member if you want to pass a `Stream`, so the rest of the properties must be in headers.

Comment: Thanks... this is exactly what i need.